# How to select element from a list and go to parent and then sibling (by Xpath)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to find a way to press button that is in the same tr as text with which I can localize specific file that I'd like to download. I'll describe it in details:

there is a website that contains many tr. Each tr contains couple child td. These td contain description and download button. I need to localize desired tr by description of its td. Then I'd like to go to td that contains download button for this tr.

Descriptions are different but I am interested only in those that contain 'DV' text. There is always couple of them on a website but I'd like to select first. What i've figured out so far is:

```
$x("//*[contains(text(), 'DV')]")[0]
```

And then I have no idea how to go to parent element and then to sibling td that contains download button.

HTML looks something like that

```
<tr>
<td class='a'>DV some other characters1</td><td class='a'>Download button code</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='a'>DV some other characters2</td><td class='a'>Download button code</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='a'>Some other description</td><td class='a'>Download button code</td>
</tr>
```

As I mentioned above- I'd like to get the first td with DV and then go to download button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to locate the first `<td>` that contains the text **DV** and identify the corresponding element containing the text **Download** you can use the following *xpath*:

```
"//tr//td[@class='a'][contains(.,'DV')]//following::td[1]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below XPath to locate first "Download" button in the same row with `td` that starts with `"DV"`

```
(//tr[starts-with(td, 'DV')]/td[.='Download button code'])[1]
```

or with `following-sibling`:

```
(//td[starts-with(., 'DV')]/following-sibling::td[.='Download button code'])[1]
```

Comment: Always something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
//td/parent::tr     - gives the parent 'tr' of 'td'
```

the exactly `xPath`I cannot provide, while not exactly understand what you want to achive. But it is not hard to find using my example. You can also find more information about xPath axes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this:

```
//td[contains(text(),'characters1')]//following::td[contains(text(),'Download button code')]
```